Why is it Incorrect to Use "For" as the Transition Here?
The question (from SAT English practice) asks "Which choice completes the text (the blank) with the most logical transition" for this paragraph:

The Y-Bridge (named for its distinctive Y-shape) was designed to span the confluence of the Muskingum and Licking rivers. _____ it crosses both rivers, Ripley's Believe It Or Not once claimed that the Y-Bridge was the only bridge in the world where it was possible to cross and still end up on the same side of the river, and Amelia Earhart once called Zanesville "the most recognizable city in the country" because of the bridge.

The answer choices are:


For
Because
While
When


My teacher said that the answer was "Because" since it shows a cause and effect relationship, but I was wondering why it can't be "For" for the same reason.

You can use "for" to explain a reason for a statement expressed before. In this sentence, "because" explains the reason/cause for a fact expressed after the clause it heads.

@fev Can "because" also explain the reason for a fact expressed before the clause it heads?

Yes, "because" can do both ways. "For" comes only after the fact for which it gives the reason/cause. Your question will probably travel to ELL.

I’m voting to close this question because it picks a weaker choice yet asks for support that "my answer is at least as good as the test answer."
